# GA4 - BigQuery links "Link" button is greyed out

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

Questions on GA4, I got editor access to a GA4 account and I'm trying to export the GA4 data to BigQuery by using the "BigQuery links" option, but the "Link" button at the top right is greyed out.

Was wondering is it cause I don't have the right access or cause we have exceeded our limit (warning message above). Any help guidance would be appreciated thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need some permissions to be able to link GA4 and BQ

Check out this [document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9823238?sjid=3740152516347658533-AP#permissions&zippy=%2Cin-this-article)